# What is the best way to dry something that is quite thick?

Tags: hydraulics

I wonder what is the best way to dry something that is quite thick. The gravity will attract the water down, but the sun will "elevate" the water.

- So I can choose to flip the object every 30 min so that each side gets the same amount of sun that will evaporate the water. But at the same time, the water that was slowly getting downward thanks to gravity will "travel" back to the other side because gravity is now attracting it to the other side. So, each time I turn the object the water inside the object will be kind of "stuck in the thickness".
- Because of this gravity attraction, I can choose to only flip the object once every 2 hours or once every 6 hours.
- Capillarity should also be taken in account.

I wonder which would be the best interval between 2 flips based on these conditions:

- Let's the object is a latex mattress that was completely submerged in a swimming pool (20cm thick, 170 long and 110 wide)
- Let's say it will dry in a garden (not in contact with the grass), under sunny condition (about 25°C), with a humidity of about 65%, and low wind (let say between 11.9 and 19.7 km/h ―or 7.4–12.2 mph― : Level 3 on the Beaufort scale)

I also wonder which of these 3 factors, evaporation, gravity or capillarity would be the major one first at the beginning of the drying and then toward the end?

Comment: Much will also depend on the temperature & humidity, as well as the moisture content of the item being dried. Drying something in an Antarctic winter will yield different result to drying it in the Sahara desert during summer.

Comment: @Fred, thanks for helping me being more specific. Temperature is 25°C and I've added the humidity percent (sorry for this mistake).  I don't really get what you mean by "moisture content of the item": I guess a first it's 100% (the item was submerged in a swimming pool) and at the end it should be 0% (totally dry)

Comment: I don't have any experience with open cell materials, but I would assume that they behave much differently from a material where water can flow more easily, I.e. Clay. The pore size might be so small that gravity has little effect when compared to surface tension or capillary action.

Comment: By what mechanism are you suggesting the sun acts against gravity with respect to absorbed moisture?

Comment: @Air. Sorry if I wasn't clear. I don't think the sun acts against gravity. To me, it' the act of flipping over the mattress that will act against gravity or more exactly that will switch the side of the attraction forcing the water attracted by the gravity to make something like "round trips" from on side to another back to the first... instead of being constantly attracted to the same side

Comment: @hazzey I have actually let the mattress in a position with an inclination of 45° for about 2-3h and the water was clearly attracted to ground by gravity (that was right after it was out of water so the volume of water in the mattress during that period was at the maximum).

Comment: Real world/desperate:  Squeeze out as much as you can. Twist in spiral for more compression/. Start at one end and work along to drive water along length as well as out. Allowable damage limits upper load allowed. | Bang on solid surface to "shock" water out.

Answer (score 5):

Solar heating would not "elevate" moisture in the object, but instead evaporates whatever is on the sunny side, allowing moisture from the bottom to soak back up by capillary action.

Your best bet (if you can) would be to set the object on the end with the least surface area, such that gravity pulls the water out the bottom faster.  Setting on its end forces the contained water (not supported by capillary action) to pool deeper, which gives the water at the bottom more pressure to flow out.  Setting it on its narrow end also allows more area to be exposed for evaporation.

After some period of time (based on the material and size), the primary method of losing water will switch from gravity flow to evaporation.  At this point, it would be best to flip the object to the other end as frequently as possible, since the evaporation will happen faster where the object has more moisture, so you want it as uniform as possible on the portion with the large surface area.  Here, mounting it on the narrow end helps again, since then it takes the remaining water longer for the moisture to slowly flow from one end to the other by gravity.

Answer (score 2):

Anything can dry with enough time and in the right conditions. The mattress left in 65% humidity will eventually be full of air at 65% humidity.

The bigger question in most real world scenarios is time to dry; because like in this situation the object will mold within days and will take weeks or months to be low enough moisture not to mold.

The most economical solution would be vacuum bagging the entire mattress and pulling vacuum on it for probably a week. This would help inhibit mold growth (not guaranteeing that) and will accelerate the drying process. In an industrial setting a larger vacuum pump could be used and the drying process could occur much faster.

For the record, gravity has no influence on evaporation, they are separate areas of science. Gravity may make one side more wet by transporting via capillaries; which is perhaps a design consideration but is not related via science. The capillary structure, the material's gas permeability, temperature, pressure, and relative humidity are the primary factors that influence drying time.

Comment: Your comment that "gravity has [no] influence on evaporation" and that "they are separate areas of science" is not actually true. Vapor pressure of anything is very related to gravity because gravity is the reason for atmospheric pressure.

Comment: True, that is a link between the two. Good catch. I was mainly trying to drive home the fact that there is no magical "gravity attraction" force changing the rate of evaporation.

Comment: Using a vacuum to dry does not really seem an economic solution to me. At 25°C, water vapor pressure is ~32 mbar, thus the gas density (assuming an ideal gas) is ~0.023 kg/m³ as opposed to the liquid density of ~1000 kg/m³. This means you have to suck out 1000/0.023 = 43230 times the volume of the liquid water in the matress. It's probably the quickest, but it's not economic.

Comment: @Robin, well, economic in comparison to heat drying it. If water can be removed by mechanical means; such as squeezing the water out that would certainly be the preferred initial approach.